# How to take difference in a specific dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, diff

I'm trying to take a difference of consecutive numbers in one of dataframe columns, while preserving an order in another columns, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4], 
           "B": [2,1,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,4],
           "C": [2.1,2.0,2.2,1.2,1.1,1.0,3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3]})

In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   A  B    C
0  1  2  2.1
1  1  1  2.0
2  1  3  2.2
3  2  3  1.4
4  2  2  1.2
5  2  1  1.0
6  3  1  3.0
7  3  2  3.3
8  3  3  3.6
9  4  4  4.0
```

I would like to:
- for each distinctive element of column A (1, 2, 3, and 4)
- sort column B and take consecutive differences of column C

without a loop, to get something like that

```
In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
    A   B     C    Diff
0   1   2    2.1   0.1
2   1   3    2.2   0.1
3   2   3    1.2   0.2
4   2   2    1.1   0.2
7   3   2    3.1   0.3
8   3   3    3.2   0.3
```

I have run a number of operations:

```
df2 = df.groupby(by='A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = ['B'])['C'].diff())
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
df4 = df3.set_index('level_1')
df5 = df.copy()
df5['diff'] = df4['C']
```

and got what I wanted:

```
df5
Out[1]: 
   A  B  C     diff
0  1  2  2.1   0.1
1  1  1  2.0   NaN
2  1  3  2.2   0.1
3  2  3  1.2   0.1
4  2  2  1.1   0.1
5  2  1  1.0   NaN
6  3  1  3.0   NaN
7  3  2  3.1   0.1
8  3  3  3.2   0.1
9  4  4  3.3   NaN
```

but is there a more efficient way of doing so?
(NaN values can be easily removed so I'm not fussy about that part)

Comment: Not sure I understand the expected result. Why are there less rows in the result?

Comment: The example doesn't make sense to me. Can you please explain how the diff is calculated and where is 4 in the A column and why col B is not sorted?

Comment: For A=4 there is no difference calculated because we need at least 2 values to take a difference. Column B is not sorted because I'm looking for a one-liner solution if possible...

Comment: For example the following `df.groupby(by='A')['C'].diff().dropna()` gives me a series of required differences only if column B were sorted in advance, which is not yet.

Comment: `df.groupby(by='A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = ['B']))` would sort it the way I want, but how do I combine it with taking a difference in a way above?

Comment: Yup, exactly you need to groupby, then in the lambda you can `.diff` it... but you will need to presort the df to be able to assign it back correctly. See the EDIT2 on my answer.

Comment: `df.groupby(by='A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = ['B'])['C'].diff())` gives me what I want, but not sure yet how to replicate the whole dataframe, with columns A, B and C (the last one to contained those differences)

Comment: @Binks Did you see my EDIT2? The problem with that one liner is 1) you will need to "flatten" (ungroup) it out and 2) you will need to use to merge to get it back, because the original df is not ordered in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little unclear on what is expected as result (why are there less rows?).

For **taking the consecutive differences** you probably want to use `Series.diff()` ([see docs here](http://Categories%20should%20be%20equally%20important,%20but%20may%20have%20different%20number%20of%20features))

```
df['Diff'] = df.C.diff()
```

You can use the `period` keyword if you wanted some (positive or negative) lags to take the differences.

Don't see where the **sort** part comes into effect, but for that you probably want to use `Series.sort_values()` ([see docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html))

---

**EDIT**
Based on your updated information, I believe this may be what you are looking for:

```
df.sort_values(by=['B', 'C'], inplace=True)
df['diff'] = df.C.diff()
```

---

**EDIT 2**
Based on your *new* updated information about the calculation, you want to:
- groupby by A (see docs on `DataFrame.groupby()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html))
- sort (each group) by B *(or presort by A then B, prior to groupby)*
- calculate differences of C (and dismiss the first record since it will be missing).

The following code achieves that:

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B'], inplace=True)
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['C'].diff()).values
df2 = df.dropna()
```

**Explanation of the code:**
First line sorts the dataframe first.

The second line there has a bunch of things going...:

- First `groupby` (which now generates a *grouped DataFrame*, see the helpful [pandas page on split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) if you're new to the groupby)
- then obtain the differences of C for each group
- and "flatten" the grouped dataframe by obtaining a series with `.values`
- which we assign to `df['Diff']` (that is why we needed to presort the dataframe, so this assignment would get it right... if not we would have to merge the series on A and B).

The third line just removes the NAs and assigns that to `df2`.

---

**EDIT3**
I think my EDIT2 version is maybe what you are looking for in, a bit more concise and less aux data generated. However, you can also improve your version of the solution a little by:

```
df3.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)  # no need to reset and then set again
df5 = df.copy()      # only if you don't want to change df
df5['diff'] = df3.C  #  else, just do df.insert(2, 'diff', df3.C)
```

Comment: Column A - these are "categories", column B - these are to be sorted, and column C - these are to be differentiated. Out of n numbers I should get n-1 differences.

Comment: Ah, ok. See my edit. Let me know if my understanding of the question is correct

Comment: As a result I'm getting wrong differences. I did prescribe exact result in my question.

Comment: I want to obtain differences within subsets of rows, eg. for values of column equal to '1' calculate differences, there are 3 numbers, I should get 2 differences, plus it should be sorted by column B, so the C series is 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and it results in differences 0.1, 0.1 (if I won't sort by B then I may get something like -0.1, 0.2, which I don't want to)

Comment: Ah, now I understand. See my second edit. That produces the result you posted.

Comment: oh I just noticed your reply, I edited my original question with some solution, will have a look at your one :)

Comment: @Binks : I added an EDIT3 that polishes your solution a bit :)

Comment: thanks! your solution is what I'm looking for, just getting it up and running for my big database with horse races ;) I can't upvote you because I have not enough reputions...

Comment: Glad it helped! I think you can accept the answer, so as to close it for future reference.